# CSS effect for hover off

Tags: css, reactjs

I am working on animation in React app.
I need animation starts working after **hover off**. I tried **:hover:after** css but does not work. Animation can work after hover over the image but I need to start after hover off. After hover over the image the colour of image can be changed and button can be appeared that is good but **after hover off**, animation should start working and button starts moving down that does not work.
how can I do that ?

```
       //animation
            **@keyframes rotate-before {
                0%   { right:0px; top:0px;}
              25%  { right:40px; top:0px;}
              50%  {bottom:10px; top:178px;right:40px;}
              }**
     
        
          
        
            .content {
              position: absolute;
              inset: 30px;
              z-index: 3;
              display: flex;
              flex-direction:column;
              align-items: center;
              justify-content: center; 
            }




    
            **.content:hover .button{
              padding: .8rem .1rem;
              background-color: #00092C;
              border:none;
              border-radius: 50%;
              cursor: pointer;
              color: #fff;
              visibility:visible;
              position: relative;  
            }**
        


        
        // this part does not work.
            .content:hover::after .button{
                padding: .8rem .1rem;
                background-color: #00092C;
                border:none;
                border-radius: 50%;
                cursor: pointer;
                color: #fff;
                visibility:visible;
                position: relative;
                 animation: rotate-before 5s linear infinite;    
              }
        


        
            .content .button{
                padding: .8rem .1rem;
                background-color: #00092C;
                border:none;
                border-radius: 50%;
                cursor: pointer;
                color: #fff;
               position: relative;
               visibility:hidden;
               transition: 0.04;
              }



        
            .content img {
              position: absolute;
              width: 100%;
              height:100%;
              object-fit: cover; 
            }



            .box:hover .content img {
              opacity: 0.3;
            }



            .box:hover .content {
              background-color: #fff;  
            }
        
        

        
            const anm = () => {
        
                return(
                    <div className={classes.flex}>
                        <div className={classes.box}>
                        <div class={classes.content}>
                        <img src="https://budgetreno.ca/wp-content/uploads/Pylon-25_compressed-thegem-portfolio-metro.jpg" alt=""/>
                        <button className={classes.button}>Follow</button>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
        
            };
```

Comment: i think you need js for this check `mouseout` event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseout_event

Answer (score 2):

**React** provide its own event system call `SyntheticEvent`

> A synthetic event is a cross-browser wrapper around the browser's native event

To listen mouse event you can find the listed mouse event in their docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events). In your case we can use `onMouseLeave` event and change elements style by adding or removing class from the `classList` of target element.

```js
// manipulate element style
const doSomething = (e) => {
  e.target.classList.add('blue');
  buttonRef.current.classList.add('show');
};

// listen to mouse leave event
<div className="square" onMouseLeave={doSomething}>
  hover me
</div>
<button ref={buttonRef} className="hidden">
  button
</button>
```

You can checkout [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bygzma?file=src/App.js) here.

Or you can use [framer-motion](https://www.framer.com/docs/gestures/#hover)

Comment: that was helpful, thanks. I used  framer-motion to fix it.